# Standard for linking to multiple URLs in support of one topic

Tags: discussion, markdown, hyperlinks

Let's say I'm discussing something in meta and I want to link to a question or answer to support my point:

> It is [considered acceptable](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999) to remind a user to mark your answer
>   as the solution.

What's the standard way on SO to handle linking to multiple URLs instead of just one in this scenario?

> It is considered acceptable<sup>[[1]](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999)[[2]](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/65034)[[3]](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/15009)</sup> to remind a user to mark your answer
>   as the solution.

Comment: Actually, I do like option 2. Very "Wikipedia-esque" of you.

Comment: @AlEverett Do you think it would need the equivalent of a [citation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation) "references section" to be complete?

Comment: I added an answer below with this style of linking.

Answer (score 4):

My preferred way is to linkify each word like this:

> It is [considered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999/176312) [acceptable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65034/176312) to [remind](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15009/176312) a user to mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: What if you have a different number of links to words? I could see doing this if each URL was somehow "more" associated with that particular word than the others.

Comment: If I run out of words to linkify, I will sometimes re-word the comment to be longer, or add "Also, see here and here". Personally, I find lots of links in things like that to be _fun_ and it always makes me smile, but that could just be my own strange sense of nerdy entertainment from simple cleverness.

Comment: +1, as the second option is harder to target.

Answer (score 3):

"Best"?

I don't know about "best", but this seems like a good way:

> It is [considered acceptable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999/176312) to remind a user to mark your answer
>   as the solution. (See also: this [answer from Steve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65034/176312) and this [other answer with a slightly different take](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15009/176312).)

It doesn't interrupt the flow of the original sentence while also indicating that there's more information to be had.

Comment: I've seen the "this and this" and "here and here" approach, but I don't like it. To me this is like using ["Click Here" as link text](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere).

Comment: @Keith: True enough. Jakob Nielsen would rap my knuckles. I'll update my answer.

Comment: But is linkifying "this and this" better or worse than linking "random" words in the sentence?

Comment: I like your updated answer better. I just wonder if a document that does alot of this would get cluttered.

Comment: [tangent](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)

Comment: Updated question: "best way" changed to "standard way on SO".

Comment: @cdeszaq I think linking random words is worse than linking, "here, here and here" (although I don't like either, see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

I would always qualify the link with something useful, not just a random word or a number (I went into detail in a recent post: [Link formatting in posts of established users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118260/172756)). For an answer, the useful piece of data is the question title and/or the answerer's name.

> It is considered acceptable ([@BilltheLizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999/172756), [@Peter Ajtai](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65034/172756), [@bananakata](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15001/172756)) to remind a user to mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be some interest in the [citation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation) style, so I have added this answer judge interest in it:

> It is considered acceptable<sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999/176312) [[2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65034/176312) [[3]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15009/176312)</sup> to remind a user to mark your answer
>   as the solution.
>
> ...botom of post...
>
> 1. [Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999/176312) by [@BillTheLizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) - [Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14994/176312)
> 2. [Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65034/176312) by [@PeterAjtai](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/148317/peter-ajtai) - [Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14994/176312)
> 3. [Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15009/176312) by [@squillman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/75852/squillman) - [Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14994/176312)

Leaving off the superscript tag would allow for a bigger target:

> It is considered acceptable[[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999/176312)[[2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65034/176312)[[3]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15009/176312) to remind a user to mark your answer
>   as the solution.